# Undefind type not filter in skipWhile?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I had subscribed for async pipe and one pipe retrun - > `bservable< AModel | undefined | null>`.
I compine this four pipe in combineLatest and subcribe.but I need below code excute only  -> AModel came.
So ,I used  `skipWhile(([, , , selectedA]) => !selectedA)` . but AModel -> undefind it not stop and go to exute below code. need some expert help to resolve it.

------------------code -----------------------------------

````
   combineLatest(observables)
     .pipe(skipWhile(([, , , selectedA]) => !selectedA),
       shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub))
     .subscribe(([a, b, c, selectedA]) => { }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`skipWhile` works only once**, this means that when the `selectedA` value becomes other than `null` or `undefined` `skipWhile` will pass values through afterwards, even if new value of `selectedA` is undefined.

In your example, I guess that `selectedA` value arrives and then it becomes `undefined` again, but on the second time when the `undefined` arrives, the `skipWhile` will not do anything and event will be emitted.

If you want to avoid `selectedA` being `undefined` or `null` at all times, use `filter` operator like so:

```
combineLatest(observables).pipe(
    filter(([, , , selectedA]) => selectedA !== null && selectedA !== undefined),
    shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)
  ).subscribe(([a, b, c, selectedA]) => {});
```